# Time trigger function running every ten minutes

Tags: azure-functions

I have a scheduler that will run every mid night 9 PM,it running successfully every day.

Yesterday I update some records in my db I so manually triggered (click on RUN).

then it running every ten minutes I don't why.

Can you please help on this?

Comment: What does this trigger look like? Is it some kind of Azure functionality, is it an SQL Server job, ... ?

Comment: [FunctionName("ExportMembersTotalData")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 18 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {    }

Comment: its azure function please find above..

Comment: OK, so you're using Azure Functions. Please tag your question correctly, this has nothing to do with Azure DevOps or Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the Function App or redeploy your code. That should fix it.
Also, opening the portal can also trigger the Function if `RunOnStartup` is configured.